# scrape longitude and latitude from this html using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to scrape the latitude and longitude of the restaurant from [URL](https://www.tripadvisor.in/Restaurant_Review-g306995-d2180479-Reviews-Pousada_by_the_Beach-Calangute_North_Goa_District_Goa.html). I am able to scrape other information like name, ratings but not latitude and Longitude of the hotel. Help Me!

I am attaching my code snippet. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8dbi.png)

[On inspecting the map on webpage I get this but I am not able to fetch the coordinates from it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtYtI.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another similar approach using xpath

```
lat = response.xpath('substring-before(normalize-space(substring-after(//script[contains(., "geoId:") and contains(., "lat")]/text(), "lat:")), ",")').extract_first()
lng = response.xpath('substring-before(normalize-space(substring-after(//script[contains(., "geoId:") and contains(., "lng")]/text(), "lng:")), ",")').extract_first()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I got the coordinates using your method.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
lat = re.findall(r'lat: (\d+.\d+),', response.text)
lng = re.findall(r'lng: (\d+.\d+),', response.text)
print lat, lng
```

Comment: I tried your solution. It didn't work. Also, instead of response.body we will use response.text (we can't user byte like object to match with string like pattern). I think the problem is there is no Lat, Long coordinated in the page. when I inspect the map there are lat, long in the src of the img tag. But I am unable to get that. @Verz1Lka